# Show A D3DImage With SharpDX

Tags: c#, wpf, directx-9, intptr

I intend to develop an application to get an image from a file and show it with `Directx9` . I  have used this code but I got the Error on `SetBackBuffer` Method!!

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.



     private void d3dImage_IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (d3dImage.IsFrontBufferAvailable)
                {

                    // (Re)initialization:
                    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\newuser\Desktop\3.jpg");
                    IntPtr Mysurface = b.GetHbitmap();

                    if (Mysurface != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        d3dImage.Lock();
//Error occurred this line 
                   d3dImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, Mysurface);
                        d3dImage.Unlock();
                        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cleanup:
                    CompositionTarget.Rendering -= CompositionTarget_Rendering;
                    //Sample.Cleanup();
                }
            }


      protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
                // Now that we can get an HWND for the Window, force the initialization
                // that is otherwise done when the front buffer becomes available:
                d3dImage_IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged(this,
                new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs());
            }


      private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (d3dImage.IsFrontBufferAvailable)
                {
                    d3dImage.Lock();
                    //Sample.Render();
                    // Invalidate the whole area:
                    d3dImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0,
                    d3dImage.PixelWidth, d3dImage.PixelHeight));
                    d3dImage.Unlock();
                }
            }
```

actually I want show an image in `d3dimage` in a `WPF` project. Can any one help me? I could not find good resources about `Directx` and C#!!!

Edited Using `Sharpdx` and Got new Error "'`HRESULT: [0x8876086C], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_INVALIDCALL/InvalidCall]`, "

```
s = new SharpDX.Direct3D9.Surface(IntPtr.Zero);

 SharpDX.Direct3D9.Surface.FromFile(s, @"C:\Users\newuser\Desktop\3.jpg", SharpDX.Direct3D9.Filter.None, 1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the back buffer to a `Bitmap`. You cannot do this. The back buffer must be of type `IDirect3DSurface9`. This is noted in the documentation for the [SetBackBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663104(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In order to use `DirectX9` (unmanaged) from C# (managed), you need to use a wrapper library. Are you using one? If not, there are several available. [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) and [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) seem to be the most popular. Using any of the wrapper libraries, you can create a `IDirect3DSurface9`that you render to with a `IDirect3DDevice9`, and attach that surface to your WPF control. Your rendered content will then appear in the control.

I think using `DirectX` may be overkill for what you need, but I'm not sure what the entire scope of your project is.

### Solution using SharpDX

I put together a working example that uses SharpDX to display an image within a `D3DImage`. This is very basic and doesn't include proper error handling. It's just meant to get you going in the right direction.

#### Step 1 - Create D3D9 device

To create the necessary surfaces, you will need a Direct3D 9 `Device`. The following code will create a `Device` using SharpDX.

```
//Create the d3d interface.
Direct3D d3d = new Direct3D();

//Get a handle to the WPF window. This is required to create a device.
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

//Create a device. Using standard creation param. 
//Width and height have been set to 1 because we wont be using the backbuffer.
//Adapter 0 = default adapter.
PresentParameters presentationParams = new PresentParameters(1,1);
Device d3dDevice = new Device(d3d, 0, DeviceType.Hardware, windowHandle, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentationParams);
```

#### Step 2 - Create the image surface

Create a surface to hold the image data.

```
//Create an empty offscreen surface. Use SystemMemory to allow for surface copying.
Surface imageSurface = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d3dDevice, ImageWidthPixels, ImageHeightPixels, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.SystemMemory);

//Fill the surface with the image data.
Surface.FromFile(imageSurface, "dx.jpg", Filter.None, 0);
```

#### Step 3 - Create the render target surface

Create the surface that acts as a render target. This is the type of surface required by `D3DImage`.

```
//Create the surface that will act as the render target.
//Set as lockable (required for D3DImage)
Surface target = Surface.CreateRenderTarget(d3dDevice, ImageWidthPixels, ImageHeightPixels, Format.A8R8G8B8, MultisampleType.None, 0, true);
```

#### Step 4 - Copy the image surface to the render target.

The image surface can be copied into the render target surface using the `Device.UpdateSurfaces` method. Note that in the previous steps, both surfaces were created with the same format (A8R8G8B). Watch out for this. It's necessary for surface copies.

```
//Copy the image surface contents into the target surface.
d3dDevice.UpdateSurface(imageSurface, target);
```

#### Step 5 - Attach the surface to D3DImage

You now have a surface that contains your image and that can be used with 'D3DImage`. Make sure you use the target surface, not the image source surface.

```
this.wpfImageSource.Lock();
this.wpfImageSource.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, target.NativePointer);
this.wpfImageSource.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, wpfImageSource.PixelWidth, wpfImageSource.PixelHeight));
this.wpfImageSource.Unlock();
```

#### Results

The image appears!

[image: [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS9Ne.png]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Actually it is just a challenging test somehow. By the way I do not know much about Sharpdx and other library.If you mention my code the first parameter is of type of IDirect3DSurface9 and the second one is IntPtr. I just get the image to a bitmap and then change it a IntPtr object.!! Can you post a useful code for my problem,  thank you very much dear friend

Comment: Sure, it's actually very simple in WPF. I added a small example of using the `Image` control. I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, But I have to do it by using DirectX, !!!!! 1- Get Image from file 2- Render It on a wpf d3dImage By Using Directx . not simple Image,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you still wanted to use `DirectX9`.In your code, your second parameter **must** be of type `IDirect3DSurface9`. The first parameter is a just an enum that is specifying the type that the second parameter `IntPtr` points to. So, you need to create a `IDirect3DSurface9` to use this method. And to do that, you'll need to use a library that wraps DirectX9. I can add an example of this, but I would need to know which wrapper you intend to use.

Comment: the type of wrapper is not important, I will be grateful for that. but Why should I use the wrapper, I mean isn't it possible to use the native Directx?

Comment: I think Sharpdx is better choice, because as I see Slimdx website It does not support Directx9! can't we use some Unmanaged dll of c++ instead of using wrapper,? it seems to me using unmanaged c++ and wrapper is somehow the same , right?

Comment: And Also the NEW question which is raise is that: "How to Load an Image to an IDirect3DSurface9" and use in Setbackbuffer method. Also How To render and show that image Is matter a debate.

Comment: You can create an ummanaged DLL written in C++ if you like. Most people use the wrappers because it's more "managed code friendly". Doing all of the DirectX work through natively link calls is certainly possible, but likely more painful. You'll be calling into a "black box" rather than having the DX code in your managed WPF application.

In short, you need to create a `IDirect3DSurface9` from the image and copy the surface to a render target `IDirect3DSurface9`. This second surface (render target) would be the one attached to your WPF control.

Comment: If it would be helpful, I can try and put together a working example of this process using an unmanaged C++ DLL.

Comment: I think it is very help full if you put some samples, native and with sharpdx. I searched a lot and could not find useful resources. and Also other friends who see this post can learn something new and beneficial. I really appreciate for your comments.  I try to work with Sharpdx but got a weird error , I Added it to my question .

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example using SharpDX. This should also answer your updated question regarding the SharpDX error. You needed to create the surface using the `CreateOffScreenPlain` method before filling it with image data.

Comment: The Best 
Answer